# CSS vertical align puzzle with float right and variable line height

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, right-align

I have a table where numbers are aligned to the right and texts can have more than 1 line.

http://jsbin.com/qelosicono/1/edit?html,css,output

The **vertical-align:middle** does not work with **float:right** unless I set the **line-height** which I can not set because some texts will wrap to multiple lines while other will stay single line so I don't know the line height upfront.

How do I vertically align the number to the middle of the text?

**EDIT** I am looking for solution that does not use tables - they behave too differently in too many cases to be fully substitutable for other elements.

Comment: Why do you use float instead of a table or display table/table-cell for tabular datas (because it looks like a table) ?

Comment: this is just an example. CSS should be capable of formatting this without a table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded your code, works fine with any number of rows (without tables).

http://jsbin.com/dufesexabu/1/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 4):

You could use a table, or make the divs act as a table.

http://jsbin.com/bobupetefu/2/edit?html,css,output

```css
.column {
  background-color : #aaaaff;
  width : 300px;
   display: table;
}

.row {
  border-top-color: #eeeeee;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  display: table-row;
}

.text {
  padding: 10px;
  width : 150px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.sum {
  padding: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="column">
  <div class="row">
    <span class="text">Lorem yposum dolor sit amet</span><span class="sum">1,000,000,000</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span class="text">Hello World</span><span class="sum">10,000</span>
  </div>
   <div class="row">
    <span class="text">Very long amount of text, Very long amount of text, Very long amount of text</span>
    <span class="sum">10,000</span>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Make `.row` a flexbox. Like this:

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/kanucuqidu/2/edit

**Edit:**
With `.sum` aligned right.

Add

```
.text {
    flex: 0 0 150px;
}
.sum {
    flex: 1;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/kanucuqidu/3/edit

Comment: I am sorry but the sum is still not aligned to the right in my chrome

Comment: It is supported from Chrome 31 version. Use vendor prefix like `-webkit-flex: 0 0 150px;` and `-webkit-align-items: center;`

Comment: @daniel.sedlacek add `justify-content: space-between;` to `.row`. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

I entered margin-top: -5%;
into

```
.sum {
    float : right;
    vertical-align: middle; 
    line-height: 40px;
    margin-top: -5%;
}
```

which seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

another version using css `transform`:

**css**

```
.row {
  position: relative;
  padding : 10px;
  border-top-color: #eeeeee;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.text {
  width : 150px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.sum {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  right: 10px;
}
```

**result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by making your row class a flexbox.

```
.row {
   display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding : 10px;
  border-top-color: #eeeeee;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-top-style: solid;
}
.text {
    flex: 0 0 150px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/taqirojupi/2/edit

Here's my solution. It unfortunetly only works as long as your `.sum` stays on one row (or, remains the same size). I set its position to absolute and 50% minus half of its own height, which always places it in the middle.

```css
.sum {
  position:absolute;
  right:10px;
  top:calc(50% - 8px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution uses absolute positioning on `.sum` and relative on `.row`.

Because you know the line-height, you can move `.sum` down by 50% of the container and up by 50% of the line-height.

http://jsfiddle.net/z02fgs4n/ (tested in Chrome)

The important additions below:

```
.row {
  position: relative;
}

.sum {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, OP, did you say the text on the right or the left can flow to more lines so you don't want to sent line-height?

Answer (score 0):

Daniel, I solved this using  tags in html. Please try this code.

```
MyHTML.html:-

  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <style>
     .column {

       width : 300px;
       display: table;
             }

    .row {

       border-top-width: 1px;
       border-top-style: solid;
       display: table-row;
         }

   .text {
       padding: 10px;
       width : 150px;
       display: table-cell;
       vertical-align: middle;
         }

   .sum {
      padding: 10px;
      vertical-align: middle;
      display: table-cell;
        }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>

    <div class="column">
      <div class="row">
         <span class="text">150000000  USD       =</span><span 
                         class="sum">Rs.9587972846</span>
       </div>
        <div class="row">
           <span class="text">15000000 GBP        =</span><span
                                 class="sum">Rs.1471043671</span>
       </div>

         </div>

         </body>
         </html>


     http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_align_float

           150000000 USD = Rs.9587972846
           15000000 GBP  = Rs.1471043671
```

Comment: Sorry Lee I am on my phone, can you maybe update and share the jsbin?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this....this may help you solve your problem....

```
.row{
width: 220px;
height: 50px;
border: 1px solid black;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
float:right;
```

-webkit-align-items:center;
}